# 10k Sqlite inserts faster than Realm

Tags: android, sqlite, realm

I saw multiple charts showing that inserts in Realm database are approximately two times faster then Sqlite. But when I try it myself SQLite proved to be a little faster then Realm. For my example code 10k inserts took ~ 1500ms for SQLite and ~ 2200ms for Realm. Am I doing something wrong? How can I speed up Realm? Thanks in advance.

Realm

```
long startTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();

    realm.beginTransaction();

    for(int i = 1; i < 10001; i++) {

        final Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setId(i);
        employee.setFirstName("John");
        employee.setLastName("Smith");
        employee.setAge(30);
        employee.setSalary(3000);

        realm.insert(employee);
    }
    realm.commitTransaction();

    long endTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
    long result = endTime - startTime;
```

Sqlite

```
long timestart = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();

db.beginTransaction();

for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setFirstName("John");
        employee.setLastName("Smith");
        employee.setAge(30);
        employee.setSalary(3000);

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(DatabaseContract.EmployeeEntry.COLUMN_FIRST_NAME, employee.getFirstName());
    contentValues.put(DatabaseContract.EmployeeEntry.COLUMN_LAST_NAME, employee.getLastName());
    contentValues.put(DatabaseContract.EmployeeEntry.COLUMN_AGE, employee.getAge());
    contentValues.put(DatabaseContract.EmployeeEntry.COLUMN_SALARY, employee.getSalary());

    long rowId = db.insert(DatabaseContract.EmployeeEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

}

db.setTransactionSuccessful();
db.endTransaction();

long timeEnd = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
long result = timeEnd - timestart;
```

Comment: Won't the `setId(i)` make the results biased, since I don't see it in the Sqlite version? Same could be said for the creation of the contentValues object for sqlite.

Comment: Also, why are you worried? You are indicating that for a large transaction, Realm costs 70 microseconds per insert more than SQLite (700ms / 10000 inserts). That's not very much. Just because other benchmarks on perhaps other versions of SQLite and perhaps other versions of Realm give different results does not mean that it's something worth worrying about.

Comment: Have you tried creating `final Employee employee = new Employee();` above the for loop?

Comment: setId doesn't change much. I know that result is still very good but I was amazed by benchmarks I saw. I wanted to know if something could be made better @EpicPandaForce 500ms down for Realm. Thank you :)

Comment: Is Id designated as PrimaryKey in Realm? If yes, then setId should definitely make a difference as it updates indexes. Try adding a PrimaryKey index on SQLite and measure the results again.

Comment: Also, make sure you run the benchmarks like 100-1000 times and average the times to get a more accurate picture.